# How can I fill a Polygon with a certain color on Pixmap?

Tags: libgdx

Libgdx allows to fill area on a [Pixmap](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html) just with circles, rectangles and triangles, but I need to fill complex figure that can be described with [Polygon](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Polygon.html) class, so how can I do that?

I was thinking about polygon triangulation, but it seems sophisticated to me.

May be exists some better way to fill complicated shapes with pixels?

Comment: Do you need to work on it as a `Pixmap`? Can you use a `ShapeRenderer` on a `FrameBuffer` and then get the `Pixmap` from that?

Comment: I never used FrameBuffer, can you show simple code example of what you mean please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you need the `Pixmap` for you can probably use a `FrameBuffer` to draw anything on, including complex shapes using a `ShapeRenderer`.

Using a `FrameBuffer` you get a render target where you can draw whatever you like and then get a `Texture` of that that you can then draw onto the *screen*.

An example of using a `FrameBuffer` might look like this;

```
package com.bornander.playground3d;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.Format;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;

public class Playground3DGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    private FrameBuffer frameBuffer;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        float aspectRatio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float width = 100;
        float height = width * aspectRatio;
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        // Create a FrameBuffer that is 50x50 pixels
        frameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, 50, 50, true);
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        camera.update();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Begin the FrameBuffer, this means render calls after this will
        // affect the FrameBuffer and not the screen
        frameBuffer.begin();

        // Use the ShapeRenderer to render what-ever shapes you need
        // (you can also draw anything you can draw onto the screen onto the FrameBuffer)
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        shapeRenderer.circle(0, 0, 16);
        shapeRenderer.end();

        frameBuffer.end();

        // Get the Texture from the FrameBuffer when done drawing
        Texture texture = frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture();

        // If you still need to, you can get a Pixmap from the Texture
        Pixmap pixmap = null;
        TextureData textureData = texture.getTextureData();
        if (!textureData.isPrepared()) {
            textureData.prepare();
            pixmap = textureData.consumePixmap();
        }

        // If you don't need the Pixmap, you can draw the texture directly
        // onto the screen
        spriteBatch.begin();
        spriteBatch.draw(texture, 0, 0);
        spriteBatch.end();
    }
}
```